# Why is everyone suspicious of me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, mods

A lot of NPCs say, "I don't have to take this from the likes of you!" as I walk around although I haven't done anything provocative. I play a sneak Thief/Assassin with a little magical assistance, but I've never had bounty on my head nor been caught.

Also, some of the thieves in the guild keep telling me I'm not supposed to be there endlessly if I'm in the room with the practice chests, but I'm one of their members!

What is going on and what can I do about it?

P.S. I use 124 plugins according to BOSS, so most likely it's one of those.

Comment: "Does anyone else" have this issue is not a good question to ask. Ask if we have a solution instead.

Comment: Perhaps the sight of your character is enough to cause offense? You wouldn't happen to be playing as a (half-)naked anime girl?

Comment: I'm aware the source isn't very reliable but it seems someone else have had the same problem in the first 30 minutes of gameplay. I assume he didn't have any mods at the time. http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20120318193111AAW5Aho

Comment: Could you list your installed mods?

Answer (score 3):

Are you a vampire? If so, if you haven't drunk blood in a while (2, 3 days), the NPCs start noticing your "condition".

Answer (score 1):

I have had this issue before and as far as I have noticed, if you were caught on the first guilds quest where you must pickpocket the Argonian, it can sometimes glitch up to where you are caught and despite receiving zero bounty, you will be attacked by everyone around you. Other than this getting caught by ANYONE can also glitch up. Sometimes this is caused by an overload with too many console commands in one session, or with too many spawned items in your inventory from console commands. One more thing is if you have killed anyone, (kills that you have not been seen and have not received bounty on count too) Killing certain people, if you have been really reckless or you were just kidding around and mistakenly shot an arrow or even if your follower has killed someone by mistake it can easily be the source of your problem. Even if it isn't a quest related NPC if you killed an NPC that is not already a common enemy i.e. a bandit, it can screw you over easily. Hope you can find some solution with this and I wish you the best of luck.